# how to commit from eclipse correctly?

Tags: git, eclipse, bitbucket

Hello I have the following problem I want to commit everything and the project folder in git from eclipse

i do the following

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

what I want to obtain is that when I commit it in my repository the project folder is made and all the code is inside for example
repository/myProject/foldercodes

what i get is the following
repository/foldercodes

Comment: You missed to share the `.project` file and `.settings` folder. It looks you have an outdated EGit: in the _Share Project_ dialog of the current EGit there is the field _Path within repository_ where you can enter `myProject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I get is the following repository/foldercodes

That is expected: when you are sharing a project with Eclipse, Git will look of your project folder *content* (and initialize a `.git` subfolder in it).

The remote repository can be named after your project name 'myProject', that way, when you clone it back later on, your foldercode will be inside a `myProject` folder created by Git clone and whose name is derived by default from the Git repository name.